# Setting PowerShell Display Options Property

Tags: powershell, permissions

I tried out the "Full Screen" option of the "Display Options" of PowerShell v1, and now I'm unable to set this property back to "Window". I provide my permission as an administrator to make the change back to "Window", but it has no effect. How do I get it back to "Window"?

(Of course, I imagine this is a more basic problem than setting a property of PowerShell.)

Comment: That "works on my machine", as the saying goes. I'm on XP; what are you using?

Comment: I love how my default display settings look like a blue screen when ps is in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Script Center](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/webcasts/psweek/day2qanda.mspx):

> I accidentally set PowerShell to full
>   screen. Is there any way to get it out
>   of that mode?
>
> You can right-click on the icon in the
>   left-hand corner of the PowerShell
>   window, choose properties, and then
>   configure the window to look any way
>   you want it to look.

Or you can try "Alt-ENTER" on the keyboard, which toggles between full screen and non-full screen modes.

Comment: Thanks, but the first option you suggest is what I tried; it is the approach that I mentioned required my permission as an administrator (and still had no effect even though the dialog accepted my input).

Comment: The second option you mention won't work in my situation because I'm using Virtual PC, which captures ALT+ENTER.

Comment: However, SHIFT + LEFT ALT + ENTER is not captured by Virtual PC and does toggle between the two viewing modes. I'd like to be able to set the property once and forget about it, however. Again, I think there is a more basic problem (with privileges) at work.

Answer (score 0):

Display options are set per shortcut link. Right click the shortcut on Programs > Windows Powershell 1.0. If you are launching Powershell from a a Shortcut other than Programs > Windows Powershell 1.0, you would need to apply the setting to the shortcut you are using instead.

Comment: I'm using the same shortcut to set the properties and to launch the program. No dice, but thanks.